# Elegant way to change CSS fill property whenever mouseover is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have several `svg` `polygon` elements that each visually is located on top of another `svg` `path` element. Sort of like a map divided by cities (path), and each city has an icon (polygon) on it. The polygon and path elements are grouped separately in HTML.

And I want to 'fill' a path yellow whenever a `mouseover` event is triggered on the polygon that is visually on top of it.

Here is what I have done using jQuery :

```
$('#polygon1').mouseover(function(){
    $('#path1').css('fill','#ffd03b');
});

$('#polygon1').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#path1').css('fill','#3A84C5');
});
```

Since I have quite a few polygons and paths, the code would be quite long and repetitive.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Can you show us the svg polygon and path markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you could do to make it a little shorter and easier to understand would be to use the `hover` event instead of separate `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```
$('#polygon1').hover(function() {
    $('#path1').css('fill','#ffd03b');
}, function() {
    $('#path1').css('fill','#3A84C5');
});
```

To attach to many elements there are a couple of approaches you could take. First you could just expand your selector to include all of the relevant elements:

```
$('#polygon1, #polygon2, #polygon3, #etc').hover();
```

Or, what I think is the better approach, add a common `class` to each of the elements you want to have this behavior and then target it in your selector. This means that you just have to make sure new items have the class, you don't have to remember to go edit the JavaScript code too.

```
$('.highlightable').hover();
```

To further refine things, rather than hard-coding the colors into your code I would use class switching. This could be done using `hover` with two handlers that use `addClass` and `removeClass`:

```
$('.highlightable').hover(function () {
  $(this).addClass('highlight');
}, function () {
  $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Assuming you are just changing the appearance of the highlighted item and not doing different things on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, it would be even more elegant to use a single handler that toggles the class. jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) doesn't seem to want to work with SVG, but you can use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)`.toggle()`:

```
$('.highlightable').hover(function () {
  this.classList.toggle('highlight');
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/tn7xmejb/) demonstrating this in action.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the quickest way to target any of them :

```js
$('polygon').hover(function() {

 $(this).siblings('path').css('fill','#ffd03b');

}, function() {
       
 $(this).siblings('path').css('fill','#3A84C5');
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="70" height="50">
  <path d="M 0 0 H 70 V 50 H 0" style="fill: #3A84C5"/>
  <polygon points="10,0 60,0 35,50" style="fill: orange"/>
</svg>

<svg width="70" height="50">
  <path d="M 0 0 H 70 V 50 H 0" style="fill: #3A84C5"/>
  <polygon points="10,0 60,0 35,50" style="fill: orange"/>
</svg>
```

If only there were a previous sibling selector then something like this would work :

```
polygon:hover ~ path {
  fill: #ffd03b;
}
```

And you can't manipulate the `z-index` of an `svg` to reverse the order - so jQuery it is...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS attribute to your polygons, `class="identifyPolygon"`
and then use:

```
$('.identifyPolygon').mouseover(function(){
        $('#path1').css('fill','#ffd03b');
});

$('.identifyPolygon').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#path1').css('fill','#3A84C5');
});
```